# Preloading images in background

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

I am developing an iOS app with a document viewer. Each document has many pages redered as images.

The viewer uses an `UIScrollView` and an `UIImageView` for displaying the current page.

In order to improve the responsiveness of the application I am preloading the next and the previous pages in background. I am using GCD to do this, but if the user changes the page (fe: go next) before the next image is loaded I can't cancel the background loading. Currently I am loading the page again and then preload the next image.

I am thinking that GCD is not the right way to do this. What is the best practice to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this. Use CATiledLayer as the backing layer class of an UIImageView subclass, by subclassing the class method + (Class)layerClass; . CATiledLayer draws asynchronously from the main thread automatically. For more info, refer to the CATiledLayer documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I have been reading about CATiledLayer, but I don't understand how it would help me with the preloading issue. I have UIScrollView with UIImageView inside. When I need to show the next page, I simply use [myUIImageView setImage:nextImage], nextImage has been preloaded before.

Comment: CATiledLayer draws in the background. Using CATiledLayer means you do not have to do the drawing using GCD yourself

Comment: did you try implementing my suggestion?

Comment: J2theC, thanks for your interest. I had a health problem and I didn't try it. I am loading the images with initWithContentsOfFile and I can't figure out how CATiledLayer could help. Is there another way to load an image into a UIImageView?

Comment: Please read the documentation of CATiledLayer. CATiledLayer will make sure your image views are drawn on a thread different than the main thread. I do not mean to be rude, but if you are actually having this problem, you are being extremely lazy with it. It would take you literally 40 seconds to do a test with. All you have to do is create a UIImageView subclass, overwrite the + (Class)layerClass class method to return [CATiledLayer class];, and use this new subclass as the view to show your images. It takes probably less than 40 seconds.

Comment: Once you have your subclass you can simply use whatever UIImageView initializer you are using. It's really that easy.

Comment: I think that we aren't talking about the same thing. And please, don't suppose that I am lazy, because I am not. I have read the documentation, and I have implemented the subclass (less than 10 lines of code). While the user is reading a page, I would like to preload the next page. I am implementing this with a NSOperation and I am happy with it, now I can cancel the task if I need it. 'UIImage initWithContentsOfFile' blocks the main thread, the problem is not drawing (CATiledLayer), the problem is preloading from disk without blocking the main thread. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough.